# php undefined index..using isset() with is_array()

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
if(is_array($ItemAttr["Actor"])){
  $Actors = implode(", ", $ItemAttr["Actor"]);
} else {
  $Actors = $ItemAttr["Actor"];
}
```

I'm getting `undefined index: Actor in **line 1** and **line 3**`

I guess i should use isset() function. Can anyone tell me how to combine that function with is_array() function..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but:

```
if( isset($ItemAttr["Actor"]) && is_array($ItemAttr["Actor"])){
    ....
}
```

In this case you are checking if the index exist before accessing its value.